# Powershell: Find all installed application on Win 10

Tags: powershell

I am trying to validate applications are installed on the machine from a list.
I know we have few options to get the details like using WMI (Win32_Product) and from registry.

I read many places that Win32_Product shouldn't be used as this will give the details about MSI only and it is very slow.

I tried to use the registry but that is also not giving accurate details.

I have Microsoft Teams but it is not able to find the details and considering it is not installed.

Here is the script.

```
$Global:Arch = $ENV:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
$Global:Apps = 'FakeApplication','Google Chrome','Microsoft Silverlight','Microsoft Teams'

$Global:AppsInstalled = @()
$Global:AppsNotInstalled = @()

$Global:RegDirsx64 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
                     "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
$Global:RegDirsx86 = $RegDirsx64[1]

Function Get-EachApp
{
ForEach ($App in $Apps)
    {
    If (!(Get-App)) { $Global:AppsNotInstalled += $App }
    ElseIf (Get-App) { $Global:AppsInstalled += $App }
    }
}

Function Get-App
{ (Get-ChildItem $RegDir | ForEach { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } | Where-Object { $_ -Like "*$App*" } | Select PSChildName).PSChildName }

If (($Arch -eq "AMD64") -or ($Arch -eq "IA64")) { ForEach ($RegDir in $RegDirsx64) { Get-EachApp } }
ElseIf ($Arch -eq "x86") { ForEach ($RegDir in $RegDirsx86) { Get-EachApp } }

$CompareLists = Compare ($AppsNotInstalled | Sort-Object -Unique) ($AppsInstalled | Sort-Object -Unique)
$Count = ($CompareLists | Measure-Object).Count

If ($Count -GT 0)
    {
    Write-Host "Warning: Not all applications are installed." -BackgroundColor Red
    Write-Host "Number of missing applications $Count!" -ForegroundColor Red
    "Missing applications:"
    $CompareLists | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -EQ '<='} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Inputobject
    }
ElseIf ($Count -EQ 0) { Write-Host "Information: All applications are installed." -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black }
```

In windows Add Remove programs all applications are showing it means this information is avaialble somewhere.

Is there any other WMI Class or registry path which i need to look.

Comment: [1] you are calling your `Get-App` func _before you define it_. that is known to cause problems. i would move the definition to where it belongs ... **_before it is called_**. [*grin*] [2] have you tried the `Get-Package` cmdlet yet? when i run >>> `Get-Package -ProviderName MSI, Programs, PowerShellGet, NuGet` <<< it seems to show all my installed apps. however, they also all show up with a call to the registry for all the user/machine/bitness combos. i don't know why yours don't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll get all the profile-installed apps as well using `Get-AppxPackage`. Details in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=win10-ps).

Comment: Get-AppxPackage only return the MS products. I need to find all the installed programs/application details.

Comment: It lists all modern (Store) apps, not just Microsoft. Teams in particular seems to be a problem to find by either method.

Comment: @Rocx does that include literally ***every*** installed app? Like chrome too? There are many ways in that case that it could fail.